# JAVA send Scribble over network

Tags: java, sockets, serialization, objectoutputstream

I'm working on a project for school where I'm using sockets to make a pictionary game. For the drawing of images I found [this](http://se.cs.depaul.edu/Java/chap09.html) code. I want to use version 3, since I don't need all the functionality such as figures.

Now, my sockets have been set up correctly, but unfortunately the `ScribbleCanvas` used (from the link above) isn't serializable (or that's what it looks like). Is there any way to make it like that, or an other way to send it over an `ObjectOutputStream`? Speed shouldn't really be an issue since it's only supposed to work locally, currently testing on localhost so it shouldn't be the most efficiënt way.

**edit**: I've made a quick mockup of the program where the error is, perhaps I'm making some mistakes elsewhere.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import scribble3.ScribbleCanvas;

public class Main extends JFrame{
    /* Scribble */
    public static ScribbleCanvas myCanvas;
    public static JPanel scribblePanel;

    /* TCP */
    public static ServerSocket hostServer;
    public static Socket socket;
    public static OutputStream os;
    public static InputStream is;
    public static ObjectInputStream ois;
    public static ObjectOutputStream oos;

    /* Panels & Frames */
    public static JFrame mainFrame;
    public static JPanel menuPanel;
    public static JPanel mainPane;

    /* Ohter */
    public static boolean isHost = true; // is this instance a host or not?
    public final static int DISCONNECTED = 0;
    public final static int CONNECTING = 1;
    public final static int CONNECTED = 2;
    public static int connectionStatus = CONNECTING;

    public static void initGUI(){
        menuPanel = new JPanel();
        //menuPanel = getMenu(); // some menu items

        scribblePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        myCanvas = new ScribbleCanvas();
        scribblePanel.add(myCanvas);

        mainPane = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        mainPane.add(menuPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);
        mainPane.add(scribblePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        mainFrame = new JFrame("Pictionary");
        mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        mainFrame.setBounds(200, 200, 800, 500);
        mainFrame.setContentPane(mainPane);
        mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        initGUI();

        while(true){
            switch(connectionStatus){
            case DISCONNECTED:

                break;
            case CONNECTING:
                try{
                    if(isHost){ // You are a host
                        hostServer = new ServerSocket(5454);
                        socket = hostServer.accept();
                    }else{      // You're not a host
                        socket = new Socket("localhost", 5454);
                    }

                    os = socket.getOutputStream();
                    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
                    is = socket.getInputStream();
                    ois = new ObjectInputStream(is);
                    oos.flush();

                    connectionStatus = CONNECTED;
                }catch(IOException e){
                    connectionStatus = DISCONNECTED;
                }
                break;
            case CONNECTED:
                if(isHost){
                    try {
                        oos.writeObject(scribblePanel);
                        //oos.writeObject(myCanvas);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }else{
                    try {
                        scribblePanel = (JPanel) ois.readObject();
                        //myCanvas = (ScribbleCanvas) ois.readObject();
                        mainFrame.repaint();
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is a stripped down version of the program, but it works. If you run it once with `isHost = true;` and once with `isHost = false;`, they have a connection, but then I get the following error: `java.io.NotSerializableException: scribble3.ScribbleCanvasListener`, both with sending the `JPanel` as well as the `ScribbleCanvas`.

```
java.io.NotSerializableException: scribble3.ScribbleCanvasListener
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(Unknown Source)
    at domain.Main.main(Main.java:102)
```

With line 102 referring to `oos.writeObject(myCanvas)` or `oos.writeObject(myScribble)`.

Comment: It isn't serializable? That's odd... according to another StackOverflow question, all JComponents are serializable. Which version of the class are you using, from that post?

Comment: @RobinGreen: See the edit I've made. I've tried sending solely the `ScribbleCanvas` element as well as the `JPanel` that it is in, but both give the same error.

Comment: What is the full stack trace for the NotSerializableException?

Comment: @RobinGreen: I think I've added what you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem occurs when it tries to write some fields. One of the fields of the `ScribbleCanvas` is not serializable.

I've looked at all the fields, and I've noticed which one contains an object that is not serializable. It's the listener. You need to make the listener class serializable.

Comment: So the listener of `ScribbleCanvas` isn't serializable currently? Is there an option to strip this information from the class for the receiver? The receiver should 'only' receive the drawing, and doesn't need to be able to draw. But I guess that would mean making a class mostly the same, but without the listener, and somehow being able to convert from one to another?

Comment: Good idea! Actually, no, there is no need for that - just add `transient` to the listener variable, which will prevent it being serialized.

Comment: Okay I'm not getting any errors now, so that's good. Only issue is that it still doesn't pass through the data of the object, nor does the object get refreshed.

Comment: @arbitter That's because when you reassign a variable with a new object, the old object does not get updated. Swing still has a reference to the old object. You need to `mainPane.remove(scribblePanel)` before the deserialization, and then `mainPane.add(scribblePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER)` again after the deserialization.

Comment: I used `mainFrame.repaint()`, but I guess that didn't do the trick. But it still doesn't seem to work using `.remove()` and `.add()`. I've been reading a bit through Scribble's code, and apparantly every point gets stored as a `Point` in a `Stroke`. Perhaps it would be faster sending solely the points, and adjusting Scribble's code to insert the received points and draw them, as opposed to sending the whole set of properties every time?

Comment: Instead of sending the whole `Scribble` over the network, I now send every individual `Stroke` over the network and it seems to work pretty fast! Then I added some methods to add new strokes (for the receiver) and send the strokes (sender), just need to refactor and edit Scribble's code a little more and it should be fine. Thanks!